# How to change icon of TreeTable in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable

I have simple treeTable. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf
I want to change expand and collapse icon of this treeTable. How can I do that?

Comment: See [primefaces tree arrow icon change to font awesome arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43535738/880619)

Comment: and [`FontAwesomeResourceHandler`](https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme#fontawesomeresourcehandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom icons (images), override the following CSS classes for their respective uses, on the treetable:

- `ui-icon` : to customise the expanded-row state icon (the triangle)

  ```
   .ui-icon {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-image: url("/your-image-here");
    }
  ```
- `ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-c` : to customize the collapsed-row state icon

If you want to use more modern fontAwesome 'icons', see [Change icon from jQuery UI to FontAwesome in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535738/880619)